# YAML: override properties in nested array

Tags: configuration, yaml, dry

My YAML file contains few services which are identical except for few properties and here is the example

```
services:
- name: SERVICE_NAME1
    connect_timeout: 60000
    host: HOST_NAME1
    port: 443
    protocol: https
    read_timeout: 60000
    retries: 5
    write_timeout: 60000
    routes:
      - hosts:
          - ROUTE_HOST1
        name: ROUTE_NAME1
        preserve_host: false
        protocols:
          - http
          - https
        strip_path: false
        https_redirect_status_code: 426
    plugins:
      - name: plugin1        
      - name: plugin2
- name: SERVICE_NAME2
    connect_timeout: 60000
    host: HOST_NAME2
    port: 443
    protocol: https
    read_timeout: 60000
    retries: 5
    write_timeout: 60000
    routes:
      - hosts:
          - ROUTE_HOST2
        name: ROUTE_NAME2
        preserve_host: false
        protocols:
          - http
          - https
        strip_path: false
        https_redirect_status_code: 426
    plugins:
      - name: plugin1        
      - name: plugin2
```

Is it possible to have a template for the service and then reuse it and set the SERVICE_NAME, HOST_NAME, ROUTE_HOST, ROUTE_NAME for the particular service using only YAML capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure – you can use any templating engine for that. For example [mustache](https://mustache.github.io):

###### test.yaml

```yaml
services:
{{#services}}
- name: {{name}}
  connect_timeout: 60000
  host: {{host}}
  port: 443
  protocol: https
  read_timeout: 60000
  retries: 5
  write_timeout: 60000
  routes:
  - hosts:
    - {{route.host}}
    name: {{route.name}}
    preserve_host: false
    protocols:
    - http
    - https
    strip_path: false
    https_redirect_status_code: 426
  plugins:
  - name: plugin1
  - name: plugin2
{{/services}}
```

###### input.yaml

```yaml
services:
- name: service
  host: host
  route: {host: rhost, name: rname}
```

###### usage

```
$ mustache input.yaml test.yaml
```

###### output

```yaml
services:
- name: service
  connect_timeout: 60000
  host: host
  port: 443
  protocol: https
  read_timeout: 60000
  retries: 5
  write_timeout: 60000
  routes:
  - hosts:
    - rhost
    name: rname
    preserve_host: false
    protocols:
    - http
    - https
    strip_path: false
    https_redirect_status_code: 426
  plugins:
  - name: plugin1
  - name: plugin2
```

Comment: Thanks, @flyx. I meant to have a template using only YAML capabilities, like an anchor or something like that.

Comment: @am1988 YAML is a serialisation language and has no templating or generally processing abilities. All the big YAML users (Ansible, SaltStack, …) use templating languages to do it.